# Using modules in google closure compiler

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, google-closure-compiler

I'm just trying to get a basic module working:

testA.js:

```
goog.module('foo');

exports.bar = function(){
  console.log('here');
};
```

testB.js:

```
var bar = goog.require('foo.bar');
bar();
```

And I'm running:

```
java -jar ~/Downloads/compiler.jar --js testA.js testB.js
```

which yields:

```
testB.js:1: ERROR - Closure dependency methods(goog.provide, goog.require, etc) must be called at file scope.
var bar = goog.require('foo.bar');
          ^

1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Any advice?

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be that the "var" form of goog.require is only allowed in goog.module files (or ES6 modules). Try adding `goog.module('foo.barTest');` or something to the test file.

Comment: @MatrixFrog that is correct.   It would create a global alias, which we don't want to encourage.

Answer (score 5):

Answering this myself.  So you can't require modules normally from a "normal" closure compiled `.js` file, only from a module file, which seems to be defined as any file that has `goog.module` in it.

So If in a module, `goog.require('module')` works fine.  If not in a module, `goog.module.get('module')` is needed

Comment: For a "goog.provide" file, you want both the goog.require and the goog.module.get.  The goog.module.get doesn't create a dependency, and by itself it supports circular or optionally loaded files.

Comment: @John -- So what's the difference between `goog.require` and `good.module.get` when in a providing file, assuming it exists?  And are you saying that `goog.module.get` will silently fail?  Or do you have to pass it more args?  And how do circular includes work if you have dependencies in both directions?  Do we have docs on this somewhere?